# Как обратиться к конкретному номеру списка enumerate Python

Tags: python

```
for f in enumerate(ftp.nlst(), 1):
    print(f)
```

На ftp сервере есть несколько файлов,они пронумеровано выводятся:

```
(1, 'user-2ccc659b-7f62-448e-acc0-45d227277216')
(2, 'user-deef9334-6bf4-44c3-9103-08c937e1a99e')
```

Как я могу обратиться к файлу 1 или 2?
Такое возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а зачем такие сложности, что мешает обратиться напрямую?

```
ftp.nlst()[index - 1]
```

зачем ваять `enumetate`?

```
ftp_list = [i for i in ftp.nlst()]

print(ftp_list[1 - 1], ftp_list[2 - 1])
```

Comment: А не проще `ftp_list = list(ftp.nlst())` это же тоже самое по идее )  И ещё в `enumerate` описка )